# Install python library through closed network

Tags: windows, networking

I teach Python in a high school which has an environment closured by Windows Server and denies FTP transactions and the majority of internet-accessing behavior. However, I need to install Pygame in a virtual machine Linux's (Edubuntu) within that network.

When I do: `sudo apt-get update` it doesn't work, of course. So this way I can't either install software or update it.

Which gateways/IP do I need to ask to the Server Manager to open in order to be able to use repositories in Linux? Even if it's just for the moment of installing through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have access to Internet or FTP then you have to create local repository with all packages. You have to point your `apt-get` to that local repository.

After that when you do `apt-get update` it will check in local repository and will update the packages.

If you dont have access to create repository, you have to ask your network manager to create local repo and give url for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need some Python packages you can directly use `pip` for installing packages provided on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). It's possible to create a partial PyPI Mirror using [pypi-mirror](https://github.com/openstack-infra/pypi-mirror). This way you don't need a direct connection to the internet.